# Сказуемое "называет" или — "называет первой"?

Tags: синтаксис, сказуемые

**Автор называет экономическую свободу первой в ряду предпосылок рынка.**

В этом предложении сказуемым будет просто глагол "называет" или сочетание "называет первой"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Автор называет** ― предикативная основа предложения. Называет (что?) свободу  (чем?) первой в ряду.

Из словаря: 1. НАЗВАТЬ,  св. кого-что (кем-чем или кто-что). Н. сына Андреем.

Это глагол с сильным управлением, то есть он требует обязательного наличия **дополнений** для выражения своего лексического значения